# Using sequelize.js get the list of all blogs `group by` `tags` from the table

Tags: express, sequelize.js

How can we get the list of all blogs `group by` `tags` from the `userblogs` table

sql query below:

```
select max(id) as id, max(blogdetails) as blog, tags, count (tags) as tagcount from userblogs group by tags;
```

I have tried so far;

```
 app.get('/service/listofblogs', async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const blogData = await BlogModel.findAll(
         {attributes: ['blogdetails', 'tags']},
         { group: ['tags'] }
        );
        res.status(200).json({ blogData });
      } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with single value instead of array?

```
const blogData = await BlogModel.findAll(
 {attributes: ['blogdetails', 'tags']},
 { group: 'tags' }
);
```

Comment: sorry, I am not getting the tags count though , I have tried as suggested !